# Can't enable or delete my service accounts on Google Cloud

Tags: gcloud, actions-on-google, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

I recently deleted my Google Cloud project then I restored it,
now after restoration, I can't delete or enable any of my old service accounts, though I can create new ones only also I can edit these new ones, don't know why but how can I overcome this.
my main issue is with the "projectname@appspot.gserviceaccount.com" service account, I can't enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what happened is that today and by itself, I found that everything is back to normal by itself, perhaps it took about 1 day since restoration.